# My string has hidden characters and is longer than what I can visually see?

Tags: c, string, arduino, esp32

**Problem**

I have a function which assigns data from reading a Bluetooth connection to a char array `QualArray[4][30]`, although it appears that the length of each char array is 1 char greater than the number of characters that visually appear in the array, suggesting a hidden character?

Furthermore, I add these strings to another string called 'resource' using `strcpy()`, and the length of the string resource is 5 chars more than what it should be (so the 4 additional hidden characters from QualArray makes sense but there is apparently another hidden char added??) I have printed a "_" at the start and end of the string to see if there are any empty chars at either side but there aren't.

Somehow there are hidden chars in my strings but I don't know why, any help would greatly be appreciated!

**Code**

```cpp
char resource[160] = "/macros/s/AKfycbzTAkuhTqJfi-EofdpOjBxKNlDe18fdTkOPHMOuOwvl9zbDqfPHwbb1/exec?"; //must be pre-defined buffer
char staticresource[160] = "/macros/s/AKfycbzTAkuhTqJfi-EofdpOjBxKNlDe18fdTkOPHMOuOwvl9zbDqfPHwbb1/exec?Cooker=RiceCooker&Meal=Rice&Portion=3&Method=Boil";
char QualArray[5][30];     // [Qparam][charnum]
    
char CookerQuery[20] = "&Cooker=";
char MealQuery[15] = "&Meal=";
char PortionQuery[15] = "&Portion=";
char MethodQuery[15] = "&Method=";
    
void CollectQualitativeData() {
  int Qparam=0;
  int charnum = 0;

  while(Qparam < 4) { // While Qualitative data has not been collectedQualDataCollected = 0
    
    if (SerialBT.available()) {
      char incomingChar = SerialBT.read();
    
      if (QualArray[Qparam] !="" && incomingChar == '\n') { // If the message isnt empty and the recieved char is nothing (ie if at end of word) if (message !=""
        Serial.print(QualArray[Qparam]);
        Serial.print("_");
        Serial.print("  length = ");
        Serial.println(strlen(QualArray[Qparam]));
          
        Qparam++;
        charnum = 0;
      }
        
      if (incomingChar != '\n'){ // If the incomingChar is different than \n, concatenate that char character to QualArray.
        if (charnum <30) { // if greater than maximum specified array val then ignore
          QualArray[Qparam][charnum] = incomingChar;
          charnum++;
        } 
      } else {
      }
    }
    delay(20);
  }
}
    
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  SerialBT.begin("ESP32test"); //Bluetooth device name
  //Serial.println("The device started, now you can pair it with bluetooth!");
    
  CollectQualitativeData();
  Serial.println("Complete");
  Serial.println(QualArray[0]);
  Serial.println(QualArray[1]);
  Serial.println(QualArray[2]);
  Serial.println(QualArray[3]);
  Serial.println(QualArray[4]);
    
  strcat(resource,CookerQuery); // resource + Resource_variables
  strcat(resource,QualArray[0]); 
  strcat(resource,MealQuery); // resource + Resource_variables
  strcat(resource,QualArray[1]); 
  strcat(resource,PortionQuery); // resource + Resource_variables
  strcat(resource,QualArray[2]); 
  strcat(resource,MethodQuery); // resource + Resource_variables
  strcat(resource,QualArray[3]); 
   
  Serial.print("resource=_");
  Serial.print(resource);
  Serial.println("_");  
  Serial.print("staticresource=_");
  Serial.print(staticresource);
  Serial.println("_");
  Serial.print("length static=");
  Serial.println(strlen(staticresource));
  Serial.print("length resource=");
  Serial.println(strlen(resource));
}
```

https://github.com/Conwon99/4th-Year-Project/blob/main/StringLengthIssue

**Serial Monitor Debugging**

```
    RiceCooker_  length = 11
    Rice_  length = 5
    3_  length = 2
    Boil_  length = 5
    Complete
    RiceCooker
    
    Rice
    
    3
    
    Boil
    
resource=_/macros/s/AKfycbzTAkuhTqJfi-EofdpOjBxKNlDe18fdTkOPHMOuOwvl9zbDqfPHwbb1/exec&Cooker=RiceCooker&Meal=Ric&Portion=3&Method=Boil_
    staticresource=_/macros/s/AKfycbzTAkuhTqJfi-EofdpOjBxKNlDe18fdTkOPHMOuOwvl9zbDqfPHwbb1/exec?Cooker=RiceCooker&Meal=Rice&Portion=3&Method=Boil_
    length static=125
    length resource=130
```

Comment: Don't post pictures of text — paste the text into the question as 'code'.  It's illegible on a fairly big screen; it would be worse on a mobile device.

Comment: Also, code needs to be in the question itself and not as a link. And please use the right tag - C and C++ are different languages so use only one.

Comment: You could be getting CR or NL (LF) characters in the strings.  You might be forgetting to allow for null terminators.  Since the code isn't in the question, it is hard to tell.  You could do yourself a favour by creating a function to dump a string with 'invisible' characters made visible — there are many variations.  Some give the hex code for each byte, typically 16 per line, possibly with printable characters printed at the end of the line, with dots (usually) for the non-printable characters.  Or you could highlight the non-printable characters with a hex or octal escape sequence.  Or …

Comment: When I use the code sample it doesn't format properly which is why I included an image and a link

Comment: Code formats properly if you include it correctly.  If you paste it, you precede it with a line containing three back-ticks (only), and follow it with another line containing three back-ticks (only).  Or you can select the code and press the **`{}`** button above the edit box to indent it all 4 spaces, which causes it to be formatted as code too. Back-ticks are hard to display in comments — `_```…```_`.

Comment: Thanks Jonathan, pasting it first and then highlighting it as a code sample worked

Comment: I don't see where you null terminate the read strings.  You loop until `charnum` is 30, at which point there isn't space left for a null byte too.  If you want to store strings, you need to allow for a null byte to terminate the string.

Comment: The issue was that I had control characters that I was reading, I fixed it by checking if they were control using iscntrl() and if they were I didn't include them in the string. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction

Answer (score 0):

`char[]` has null-terminator value `\0` and it is counted as the length of the array. Just use `std::vector` and `String`. Anyway, your code is uncompilable. I'll rewrite for you:

```
#include <BluetoothSerial.h>
#include <vector>

const char resource[] PROGMEM = "/macros/s/AKfycbzTAkuhTqJfi-EofdpOjBxKNlDe18fdTkOPHMOuOwvl9zbDqfPHwbb1/exec?"; //must be pre-defined buffer
const char staticresource[] PROGMEM = "/macros/s/AKfycbzTAkuhTqJfi-EofdpOjBxKNlDe18fdTkOPHMOuOwvl9zbDqfPHwbb1/exec?Cooker=RiceCooker&Meal=Rice&Portion=3&Method=Boil";

const char cookerQuery[] PROGMEM = "&Cooker=";
const char mealQuery[] PROGMEM = "&Meal=";
const char portionQuery[] PROGMEM = "&Portion=";
const char methodQuery[] PROGMEM = "&Method=";

std::vector<String> qualArray;
BluetoothSerial SerialBT;

void CollectQualitativeData() {
  while (qualArray.size() < 4 ) {
    if (SerialBT.available()) {
      String incomingChar = SerialBT.readStringUntil('\n');
      qualArray.push_back(incomingChar);
    }
    delay(20);
  }
}

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  SerialBT.begin("ESP32test");

  CollectQualitativeData();
  Serial.println("Complete");

  for (int i = 0; i < qualArray.size(); i++) {
    Serial.println(qualArray[i]);
  }

  String res(resource);
  res += cookerQuery + qualArray[0];
  res += mealQuery + qualArray[1];
  res += portionQuery + qualArray[2];
  res += methodQuery + qualArray[3];
  Serial.println(res);
}

void loop() {}
```